# C# Referencing dll's relative to an external working directory (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2015

I'm having a bit of an issue running a C# Class library I'm working on. The issue is I need to load reference dll's from a sub folder of an external working directory.

My environment is as follows:

My project files are within my normal project storage area:

```
/Documents/VS2015/Projects/..
```

This Class library has an assigned Working directory due to the nature of the application:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/ProgramName/
```

and the dll's need to be stored in a lib folder within that working directory:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/ProgramName/lib/
```

Since my debug configuration has a working directory defined, my debug builds are naturally running outside the project storage's scope.

The class library will function perfectly fine if I put the dll's in the root working directory (**C:/Program Files (x86)/ProgramName/reference.dll**), however as soon as I put the dll's in the sub folder I need them to be (**C:/Program Files (x86)/ProgramName/lib/reference.dll**) the program breaks with:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
```

I've been researching this issue for quite some time and have tried updating HintPaths in the .csproj project file, setting dependencies and probingPaths in the app.config as well as defining reference paths in the project settings, all to no avail.

Any help on how to tell my project to fetch these dll's would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Update:** Adding

```
<probing privatePath="lib"/>
```

to my app.config did not resolve the issue.

---

**Solution:**

I ended up fixing this issue by using AppDomain.AssemblyResolve:

```
AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(LoadFromSameFolder);

static Assembly LoadFromSameFolder(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        string folderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        string fp = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        int index = fp.LastIndexOf('.');
        string fpo = index == -1 ? fp : fp.Substring(0, index);
        string fpo2 = fpo + "\\lib\\";
        string assemblyPath = Path.Combine(fpo2, new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll");
        if (File.Exists(assemblyPath) == false) return null;
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
        return assembly;
    }
```

Comment: Why do the libraries have to be placed in a subfolder?

Comment: Also, incorrect duplicate link, seeing as the problem is with loading the references at runtime, not with copying them to their wanted location at compile time.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen because it makes organising large amounts of dll's easier and makes installation as simple as dropping a folder into the program directory. It's sort of a situation of I have to do it.

Comment: Look into using the [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx) event.